# http/php: header:location redirect not redirecting to right domain

Tags: php, redirect

I am setting up a mirror of an existing website on a new host in preparation for switching hosts.

The mirror is running on a subdomain of my account on the new host.  I also have the mysql database working.  However, when the php code attempts a redirect using header:location, instead of redirecting to the page at the new host, it is sending the viewer to the old host.  I can't for the life of me figure this out because I cannot find anywhere in the code that mentions the domain itself.  Paths are just relative.

Old host domain.  `mysebsite.com`

Typing in above loads `index.php.`

New mirror site domain.  `mywebsite.myaccountname.newhost.com`

Typing in above takes you to the right directory and loads the page `index.php`.

The redirects are set up as follows:

```
header("Location: products.php");
```

Instead of going to `mywebsite.myaccountname.host.com/products.php` on the newhost, it goes to `mywebsite.products.php` on the old host.

Note I did name my subdomain on the new host mywebsite--the same as the domain of the current website, but I can't see how that would matter.

Thanks for any suggestions of what could be causing this.

Comment: This is too confusing to follow. Where is `header("Location: products.php");`?

Comment: you missed the point.  It's a relative redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use:

```
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
header("Location: http://$server/products.php");
```